# Attributes value substitution with sed command

Tags: regex, xml, bash, sed

I am trying to substitute an attributes value using `sed` command,
but it is only possible to substitute value without spaces.

sample input xml:

```
<BillingAddress11300000 Tag="11300000" SectionID="BLA" CustAddrName="CLAUDIA LUCIA DE ALMEIDA" CustAddrStreet="AV ENGENHEIRO RICHARD" CustAddrState="RJ" CustAddrZip="20561-090" CustAddrStreetNo="64" CustAddrComplement="APTO 303" CustAddrCity="RIO DE JANEIRO" CustAddrCounty="GRAJAU"/>
```

The substitution should use the name of the attribute to process and the value to change that attribute to from previously variables which were previously read in.

The desired output (for $att="CustAddrName" and $value="Rodrigo DE Silva"):

```
<BillingAddress11300000 Tag="11300000" SectionID="BLA" CustAddrName="Rodrigo DE Silva" CustAddrStreet="AV ENGENHEIRO RICHARD" CustAddrState="RJ" CustAddrZip="20561-090" CustAddrStreetNo="64" CustAddrComplement="APTO 303" CustAddrCity="RIO DE JANEIRO" CustAddrCounty="GRAJAU"/>
```

I used the following script

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo "Enter the attribute name"
read att 
echo "enter new value" 
read value 
sed "s|$att\=\S*\S|$att=\"$value\"|g" test.xml>>out.xml**
```

With this script it is possible to substitute the attribute's value with this code, if the current value of the attribute is without space. But it is not possible if the value has a space.

How to implement this scenario?

Comment: @EdMorton Funnily, OP actually did provide desired output. It was however hidden behind a formatting failure. Cyrus was right, probably more than aware of.

Answer (score 0):

You want to replace a value of an attribute which contains a .
Your sed line however looks exlicitly for non-whitespace, via the regex `\S*\S`.

You should change to looking for 'everything except ", within a pair of "'.
To do so you can use:

```
sed "s|$att\=\"[^\"]*\"|$att=\"$value\"|g"
```

The output for the given xml line and `$att` = "CustAddrName" and `$value` = "new value" is:

```
<BillingAddress11300000 Tag="11300000" SectionID="BLA" CustAddrName="new value" CustAddrStreet="AV ENGENHEIRO RICHARD" CustAddrState="RJ" CustAddrZip="20561-090" CustAddrStreetNo="64" CustAddrComplement="APTO 303" CustAddrCity="RIO DE JANEIRO" CustAddrCounty="GRAJAU"/>
```

However, the really best way of manipulating XML is using an XML-parser or an XSL transformation.